# SQLとPHP配列を比較する

Tags: php, mysql, sql

PHPとMySqlでプログラムしています。

$data配列には、id（一意）,dateが入っています。
このデーターをMySQLのテーブルに挿入していきます。

MySQLには、すでに同じdateが入っていたら、その$dataを除外して、MySQLにデーターをinsertしたいとします。

シンプルに配列とMySQLテーブルのデーターを比較する方法があったら、ご教示ください。

Comment: DB上とこれから挿入しようとしているデータ量はどれぐらいでしょうか。重複の可能性はどの程度でしょうか。「除外して挿入」とありますが、問答無用で挿入してDB側の一意制約でエラーにするのはなしでしょうか。あと、自分でここまではできている、というコードがあるのであれば、それを追記してください。(上記の追加情報も、コメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 1):

一位のキーを用いて作成、更新が同時にできるものは下記のが用意されています。

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/insert-on-duplicate.html

既に存在している場合は、更新項目を日付などにして更新するか、既存のデータを上書きする形で行うことができます。データの更新がない場合は実際に更新は走らないので高速でもあります。

Answer (score -1):

データをselectして持ってきてからの比較が一番簡単かと思います。

```
select date from table_name;
```

配列にして取得してからinsertですね。

insert into .... duplicate key updateを利用する場合は、もっと簡単で更新対象を更新日とかにすればデータは更新されず済みます。